# Java Mail mystery - SMTP blocked?

Tags: java, smtp, jakarta-mail

I have a Java program which uses javax.mail to send an SMTP message.   This program works fine on a Linux box, I want to emphasize that beforehand.  When I try this same code on my Windows 7 x64 box, I get this error:

```
send failed, exception: javax.mail.MessagingException: Could not connect to SMTP host:     smtp.west.cox.net, port: 25;
nested exception is:  java.net.SocketException: Network is unreachable: connect
```

Here is the code:

```
Session session = Session.getInstance(props, null);
MimeMessage msg = new MimeMessage(session);
msg.setFrom();
msg.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO, props.getProperty("mail.to", "me@mine.com"));
msg.setSubject(mySubject);
msg.setSentDate(new Date());
msg.setContent(sBuf.toString(), "text/html");
Transport.send(msg);
```

This program pretty much uses defaults for everything.  It works fine on another box on the same network. It uses the same settings that I use for my regular mail client, which works fine. There is something on THIS Windows box that is blocking SMTP, but only for Java.

I have Symantec (Norton) 360 installed. Turning it off makes no difference, but rebooting into Safe Mode (which disables almost everything) allows the program to work and send mail just fine.

So, to recap:

1. The program code works.
2. The settings are correct.
3. SMTP works for Windows Mail and is only blocked for Java on this Windows machine.

Before I spend another day tearing things apart and uninstalling / reinstalling, I wondered if anyone had any advice on fixing this?

Comment: what happens if you try `telnet smtp.west.cox.net 25` from the command prompt?

Comment: What version of Windows? Is Windows Firewall active?

Comment: Since your code works in safe mode ... it's not your code. I suspect Java wasn't allowed via the windows firewall.

Comment: This question might better be posted in ServerFault. It's a network/OS problem, not a programming problem.

Comment: Testing port 25 from PUTTY (telnet) connects to the SMTP server as espected.

Comment: @Perception:  The Windows is Windows 7 x64, which has Norton 360 Security Suite on it.   The Norton firewall essentially "takes over" the Windows firewall.

Comment: It does not seem to be a programming related question per se. But can you check if Java itself is blocked from accessing the internet?

Comment: just a suggestion don't use 25 as smtp port beacuse it's un-secured and many mail server will detect your mail as spam

Answer (score 51, accepted):

The problem is due to the IPv4/IPv6 preference of Java.   Java tries to use IPv6 by default (?) and my ISP does not support IPV6.   However, it's enabled on my Windows 7 boxes by default.

If you are experiencing similar behavior, you can verify this by going to "Control Panel/Network and Internet/Network Connections", right-clicking your internet connection, and selecting "Status" from the context menu.  The Status dialog will display two lines similar to this:

```
IPv4 Connectivity:  Internet
IPv6 Connectivity:  No Internet access
```

This is the root of the problem - Java prefers IPv6, which it cannot use to connect to the internet.

To fix this, do either one (or both) of these things:

1. Disable IPv6 on your Windows 7 box.
2. Start your java program using this command line option:

   ```
   -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true
   ```

Doing either one of these will fix the problem.

Comment: Thanks for this explanation, fixes my issue. Someone else on stackoverflow claimed they could use their mail/Exchange server's IPv6 address as the host instead of the server's IPv4 address. but not sure that solves issues you mentioned above.

Comment: This is a really kickass answer, I was banging my head on the wall!  I would give you 100 up-votes if I could.

Comment: Just passing in JVM argument "-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true" solved my issue.

Answer (score 12):

I had the same problem during upgrade form java 1.6 to java 1.7. 
The problem occured because java 1.7 using IPv6 by default. 
To fix this, you need to add Java Option like on example below.

Just run this command on Windows cmd:

```
setx _JAVA_OPTIONS -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true
```

Comment: what are the stars for?

Answer (score 3):

[Synantec EP 12.1 RU5](http://www.symantec.com/business/support/index?page=content&id=TECH224706&locale=en_US) fixes your issue.

> Symantec Endpoint Protection blocks email sent by Java mail client
>
> Fix ID: 3399185
>
> Symptom: The Internet Email Auto-Protect feature of Symantec Endpoint Protection blocks SMTP email sent by a Java mail client.
>
> Solution: Updated the Internet Email Auto-Protect driver to allow processing of IPv4-mapped IPv6 addresses.

Answer (score 2):

I was also facing the same issue , basically it was a Java 7 issue, Just passing in JVM argument "-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true", i got rid from issue .

Comment: please add such short answers as comments

Answer (score 1):

Although this issue is solved: it might still be useful to point out that some Windows Firewalls block/allow access to ports based on the executable name (rather than purely the port number itself) - so you can end up with one program (say Outlook) being allowed and another (say Java) being blocked.

Answer (score -1):

I had similar issue but strangely everything was working fine with jdk 1.6 once I install jdk 1.7 I got the exception. I wonder what could be the reason for this!

After adding IPV4 argument it is working fine..Thank you so much.

Comment: This qualifies as a comment, not an answer.