# Change String colour JavaMail

Tags: java, colors, jakarta-mail

I am using JavaMail library, I would like to change the body of the emails, sentences in different color? How can I do it? My application is in (Swing/JFrame)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

An example of sending email as HTML: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_sending_email.htm

What Baadshah is suggesting is adding all of your color formatting inside the Content string using html tags.

```
     message.setContent("<h1>This is actual message</h1>",
                        "text/html" );
```

You can programatically construct the string that contains the body message.

```
String line1 = "This is the first line in the body.  We want it to be blue."

addColor(line1, Color.BLUE);
```

Then create a method for handling the colorizing html:

```
public static String addColor(String msg, Color color) {
    String hexColor = String.format("#%06X",  (0xFFFFFF & color.getRGB()));
    String colorMsg = "<FONT COLOR=\"#" + hexColor + "\">" + msg + "</FONT>";
    return colorMsg;
}
```

You can examine different ways of colorizing in HTML here: http://www.htmlgoodies.com/tutorials/colors/article.php/3479011/How-To-Change-Text-Color-Using-HTML-and-CSS.htm.  This includes old ways of doing it, like using FONT (as my example above) or modern ways of doing it using CSS.

Edit: The toHexString returns an 8 Character hex code (alpha + red + blue + green) while HTML only wants the RGB without alpha.  I used the solution from [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6539879/how-to-convert-a-color-integer-to-a-hex-string-in-android), and setup a SSCCE:

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.util.*;
import javax.mail.*;
import javax.mail.internet.*;

public class EmailTestHTML
{
public static void main(String [] args)
{

   // Recipient's email ID needs to be mentioned.
   String to = "targetemail@somehost.com";

   // Sender's email ID needs to be mentioned
   String from = "youremail@somehost.com";

   // Assuming you are sending email from localhost
   String host = "putYourSMTPHostHere";

   // Get system properties
   Properties properties = System.getProperties();

   // Setup mail server
   properties.setProperty("mail.smtp.host", host);

   // Get the default Session object.
   Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(properties);

   // String with body Text
   String bodyText = addColor("This line is red.", Color.RED);
   bodyText += "<br>" + addColor("This line is blue.", Color.BLUE);
   bodyText += "<br>" + addColor("This line is black.", Color.BLACK);

   System.out.println(bodyText);

   try{
      // Create a default MimeMessage object.
      MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(session);

      // Set From: header field of the header.
      message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(from));

      // Set To: header field of the header.
      message.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO,
                               new InternetAddress(to));

      // Set Subject: header field
      message.setSubject("This is the Subject Line!");

      // Send the actual HTML message, as big as you like
      message.setContent(bodyText,
                         "text/html" );

      // Send message
      Transport.send(message);
      System.out.println("Sent message successfully....");
   }catch (MessagingException mex) {
      mex.printStackTrace();
   }
}

public static String addColor(String msg, Color color) {
    String hexColor = String.format("#%06X",  (0xFFFFFF & color.getRGB()));
    String colorMsg = "<FONT COLOR=\"#" + hexColor + "\">" + msg + "</FONT>";
    return colorMsg;
}
}
```

Note:
In my environment I had to set this argument in the Run Configuration:

-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true

More on that [here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14064111/java-mail-mystery-smtp-blocked)

Comment: Integer.ToHexString(color) is showing error and "colorMsg" instead of formatting the colorMsg, the total sentence is printed in the email "<FONT COLOR = |""--msg--------"?

Comment: Sorry about that.  You want Integer.ToHexString(Color.getRGB())

Comment: The <FONT COLOR ... > is what worked for me. <div style='font-color:green'></div> did not work.

Answer (score 3):

Its just css.

Nothing to do with `JAVA`.The browser detects your HTML content which you are sending in `email`.

For example

```
<div style="font-size:14px">Dear user</div>
```

Comment: could you explain, because I have no idea about CSS and html, Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You have to send the mail in HTML format to be able to change text color.

See the [JavaMail FAQ](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/faq-135477.html).

Answer (score 0):

For me this worked flawlessly, Worth a shot :

```
String htmlText2 = "<font color=red>Jon Targaryen</font>\n";
```

or if you want to use hex color :

```
String htmlText2 = "<font color=#93cff2>Jon Targaryen</font>\n";
```

You can add more attributes like Headings or Bold :

```
String htmlText2 = "<H1><font color=red>Jon Targaryen</font></H1>\n";

String htmlText2 = "<b><H1><font color=red>Jon Targaryen</font></H1></b>\n";
```