# ColdFusion 10 Can't Verify Exchange 2010 Mail Server

Tags: email, coldfusion, exchange-server

So I've been running CF9 on Linux for a while and using CFMail to send email through a client's Exchange 2010 server for quite a while.

We're attempting to migrate to CF10 on Win2008, IIS7.5.  Everything is set and ready to go except I can't get CF10 to verify the mail connection?  I've got both mail settings (CF9 and CF10) set the exact same way and can view them open side by side and verify they're identical.  However, while the CF9 verifies successfully the CF10 system fails??

I tried sending through CFMail tags while specifying the server credentials and see this in the CF10 log:

```
"javax.mail.AuthenticationFailedException: No authentication mechansims supported by both server and client"
```

What does this mean?  I know my authentication credentials are correct because I'm able to connect in CF9.

I've turned off all firewalls and still nothing.  So, I then tried installing CF10 on my Mac laptop.  It, too, will not verify the mail connection!

Is there a known problem with CF10 connecting to an Exchange mail server?

Any ideas?

Comment: have you installed all the cf10 updates?

Comment: Yes, all updates are applied.  I found a solution and edited the posting.

Answer (score 3):

I "solved" this.

I could find little online and received no comments to this thread. No combination of settings I tried would work and I have no access to the client's mail server. The person who runs that server couldn't run a lemonade stand so no help there.

Then I stumbled across [this page](https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/JIRAKB/No+authentication+mechansims+supported+by+both+server+and+client+when+Configuring+Microsoft+Exchange+SMTP+Server). Nothing to do with ColdFusion but seemed like a similar issue.

> Recent changes in the JavaMail API has changed certain authentication
>   defaults and sometimes will create an authentication error with some
>   Exchange Server environments dependent on the configuration.

I'd never put much thought into CFMail because it was always drop dead simple and simply worked. Focusing on this link's Resolution 2 (ie replace the mail.jar with an older version). I wondered if CF used JavaMail and if I could downgrade CFMail? I cracked open CF's `mail.jar` file and found that CFMail does, indeed, use the JavaMail API. So, I then checked the ColdFusion docs to see if any new features were added to CFMail between CF9 and CF10. None.

So, I swapped out the `mail.jar` file from my CF9 install to CF10 and restarted. Boom! Everything worked immediately. As far as I can tell I've had no compatibility issues to report.

Answer (score 0):

Swapping the mail.jar did not work for me.  However, adding the following to JVM arguments

-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true

worked for me.  Please refer to the following article

[Java Mail mystery - SMTP blocked?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14064111/java-mail-mystery-smtp-blocked)

posted by another user