# SocketException when connecting to SMTP server, but with telnet it's working

Tags: java, email, smtp, telnet, socketexception

I want to send an email via Java but unfortunately I'm getting the following exception:

```
javax.mail.MessagingException: 
    Could not connect to SMTP host: localhost, port: 25;
        nested exception is:
            java.net.SocketException: Permission denied: connect
```

I'm using [this little example program](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_sending_email.htm) to send my email.

However when trying to connect to the server with

```
telnet localhost 25
```

I'm able to establish a connection.

The same situations occurs with a remote SMTP server.

What could be the problem?

---

Here the output with `mail.debug` set to `"true"`:

```
DEBUG: JavaMail version 1.4.7
DEBUG: successfully loaded resource: /META-INF/javamail.default.providers
DEBUG: Tables of loaded providers
DEBUG: Providers Listed By Class Name: {com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPSSLTransport=javax.mail.Provider[TRANSPORT,smtps,com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPSSLTransport,Oracle], com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport=javax.mail.Provider[TRANSPORT,smtp,com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport,Oracle], com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPSSLStore=javax.mail.Provider[STORE,imaps,com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPSSLStore,Oracle], com.sun.mail.pop3.POP3SSLStore=javax.mail.Provider[STORE,pop3s,com.sun.mail.pop3.POP3SSLStore,Oracle], com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPStore=javax.mail.Provider[STORE,imap,com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPStore,Oracle], com.sun.mail.pop3.POP3Store=javax.mail.Provider[STORE,pop3,com.sun.mail.pop3.POP3Store,Oracle]}
DEBUG: Providers Listed By Protocol: {imaps=javax.mail.Provider[STORE,imaps,com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPSSLStore,Oracle], imap=javax.mail.Provider[STORE,imap,com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPStore,Oracle], smtps=javax.mail.Provider[TRANSPORT,smtps,com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPSSLTransport,Oracle], pop3=javax.mail.Provider[STORE,pop3,com.sun.mail.pop3.POP3Store,Oracle], pop3s=javax.mail.Provider[STORE,pop3s,com.sun.mail.pop3.POP3SSLStore,Oracle], smtp=javax.mail.Provider[TRANSPORT,smtp,com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport,Oracle]}
DEBUG: successfully loaded resource: /META-INF/javamail.default.address.map
DEBUG: getProvider() returning javax.mail.Provider[TRANSPORT,smtp,com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport,Oracle]
DEBUG SMTP: useEhlo true, useAuth false
DEBUG SMTP: trying to connect to host "localhost", port 25, isSSL false
```

Comment: it clearly stats `Permission Denied`, you need to pass auth info to connect to `SMTP` server or there is some issue with your java `smpt` client configuration..

Comment: @harsh I don't pass any auth info with telnet and there it's working.

Comment: Try setting `props.put("mail.debug", "true")` assuming `props` is your `Properties` instance, it would print smtp internal logs on console, this may help in debugging further

Comment: @harsh Unfortunately this doesn't change anything. When retrieving this property it evaluates to `null`.

Comment: @hash I was wrong: I've set it to `false` instead of `true`.But the output isn't very helpful: `DEBUG SMTP: trying to connect to host "localhost", port 25, isSSL false
`

Comment: Can you add the output with your question above, there might be some clues..

Comment: @harsh I've added the output.

Comment: Added a program with alternate smtp server, you may try that..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't agree with harsh (sorry, can't comment where i should, not enough reputation). The Permission denied error happens within the connect system call, so it's way before the client can even try to authenticate to the server.

Unfortunately, you don't provide any information about which system you're running on - windows, linux, some other unix or something completely different.

I had this kind of problem once in a company where the local McAffee on all client PCs was configured to prevent all traffic to port 25, so if a client caught a virus, it still wouldn't be able to mailbomb others. Maybe something like that is running on your system?

Or, maybe it's a problem with ipv4 (which i assume you're using from java) being blocked, but ipv6 allowed. Try do do a netstat after telnet connects to find out which one it's using. But again, i'd assume it has to do with the firewall settings on your computer, which might allow one of the IP protocols but not the other.

Comment: firewall issue looks less likely to me (`host: localhost, port: 25`), unless harold performed some changes on local box... and `telnet` was able to connect too. Now on `auth` it's again ruled out as `telnet` client was too didn't use any `auth` info, I missed that and was basing on `exception` @Harold which `smtp` server you have setup on you machine and any specific configuration done??

Comment: @harsh I'm running Windows 7 inside a company. The problem occurs with my local Mercury Mail SMTP server as well with a remote test server.

Comment: @harsh The problem was that IPv6 has been blocked. See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14064111/java-mail-mystery-smtp-blocked

Comment: Great, I guess `telnet` isn't using `IPv6` and hence worked; a good pointer to remember.

Answer (score 1):

For sending the mail through your application via SMTP you need the IP of the machine to be relayed on the SMTP server.

Get the Ip relayed on SMTP server. Henceforth, you will be able to send the mails and wont get the exception as Permission denied

Comment: Could you elaborate a little bit on your answer? How can I configure this?

Comment: Can you please let me know the SMTP server you are using?

Comment: I'm using Mercury Mail.

Comment: Check out this link,http://www.open-emr.org/wiki/index.php/Mercury_Mail_Configuration_in_Windows

Answer (score 1):

I had the similar issue. After spending few hours, finally resolved issue by putting below line in code:

```
System.setProperty("java.net.preferIPv4Stack" , "true");
```

By default, Java uses ipv6, and I was passing ipv4 address. After putting above line, It worked.

Answer (score 0):

You may try following program to check with gmail smtp server (assuming you have gmail account), if this works fine surely you have some issue with Mercury mail server setup:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    String host = "smtp.gmail.com";
    String username = "your-gmail-username@gmail.com";
    String password = "gmail-password";
    Properties props = new Properties();
    props.put("mail.debug", true);
    Session session = Session.getInstance(props);
    MimeMessage msg = new MimeMessage(session);
    msg.setFrom(new InternetAddress(username));
    msg.setRecipient(RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress(username));
    msg.setSubject("This is the Subject Line!");
    msg.setContent("<h1>This is actual message</h1>",
                       "text/html" );
    Transport t = session.getTransport("smtps");
    try {
        t.connect(host, username, password);
        t.sendMessage(msg, msg.getAllRecipients());
    } finally {
        t.close();
    }
}
```