# java mail javax.mail.MessagingException: exception

Tags: java, email

Below is the code  I am using for testing purpose (I used the same librarires which are used in my project).

```
package test;

import java.util.Properties;
import javax.mail.*;
import javax.mail.internet.*;

public class EmailSender {
  public static void send(String from, String password, String to, String sub, String msg) {
    // Get properties object
    Properties props = new Properties();
    props.put("mail.smtp.host", "smtp.gmail.com");
    props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.port", "465");
    props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.class", "javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory");
    props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
    props.put("mail.smtp.port", "465");
    // get Session
    Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props, new javax.mail.Authenticator() {
      protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
        return new PasswordAuthentication(from, password);
      }
    });
    // compose message
    try {
      MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(session);
      message.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress(to));
      message.setFrom(new InternetAddress("sannavdev@gmail.com"));
      message.setSubject(sub);
      message.setText(msg);
      // send message
      Transport.send(message);
      System.out.println("message sent successfully");
    } catch (MessagingException e) {
      throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }

  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {


    final String fromEmail = "sannavdev@gmail.com"; // requires valid gmail id
    final String password = "sannavdev@1234"; // correct password for gmail id
    final String toEmail = "vethsa.teja@broadcom.com"; // can be any email id

    EmailSender.send(fromEmail, password, toEmail, "hello javatpoint", "How r u?");
  }
}
```

Code is running fine in eclipse. But when I run the code in IPV 6 environment I am getting below error:

> Failed to sent mail javax.mail.MessagingException: Could not connect to SMTP host: smtp.gmail.com, port: 465;
>     nested exception is:
>           java.net.SocketTimeoutException: connect timed out

Comment: Looks like a firewall is filtering the connection.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Java Mail mystery - SMTP blocked?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14064111/java-mail-mystery-smtp-blocked)